# TypeError: (0 , _testUtils.createLocalVue) is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

This is my code. Can some please help me figure out the error.I am using jest to test out my frontend which I have built using Vue.The line const localVue = createLocalVue(); is giving out the error TypeError: (0 , _testUtils.createLocalVue) is not a function

```
import { createLocalVue,shallowMount  } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import getters from '../../src/store/module/auth/getters.js'
import TheHeader from '@/components/layout/TheHeader.vue'



// const store = new Vuex.Store({
//     state: {
//         user:null,
//         token:'',
//         expiresIn:null,
//         isUserLoggedIn:false,
//         isAdminLoggedIn:false,
//     }
//   })


describe('TheHeader', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(Vuex);
  let store
  let state
 
  it('Checks whether the login is correctly displayed', () => {
    const cmp = shallowMount(TheHeader, { store,localVue})
    expect(cmp.name()).toMatch('TheHeader')
    expect(cmp.vm.isLoggedIn()).toBe(false)
  })

})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`createLocalVue` was removed in version 2 of `@vue/test-utils`, which explains why it's undefined in your example.

- To install a Vue plugin (such as Vuex), use the [`global.plugins` mounting option](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-plugins)
- To mock instance APIs (such as `this.$store`), use the [`global.mocks` mounting option](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-mocks)

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import TheHeader from '@/components/TheHeader.vue'

const store = /* Vuex store */

const cmp = shallowMount(TheHeader, {
  global: {
    plugins: [Vuex],

    // OR:
    mocks: {
      $store: store,
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import App from '@/views/Home'
```

creating a fake store

```
const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      user: {},
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count += 1
    },
  },
})
```

Creating the Component

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(store)
let wrapper
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(App, {
    global: {
      plugins: [store],
    },
    computed: { showAlert: () => false },
  })
})
```

now you can do the test

```
test('Home', async () => {
  expect(wrapper.vm.showAlert).toBe(false)
})
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations to your answer please ? :)